# Run .sh (no service) file on startup

Tags: centos, boot, sh

How to execute a script once at startup time on CentOS 6.3? I added file with following containment

```
#chkconfig: 2345 95 20
#description: Some description
sh /opt/somePath/my.sh
```

into */etc/ini.d* and it works fine (I executed required `chmod`, `chkconfig`).

But *my.sh* file is **compatible to run as service**. And when I try to run in same way another .sh file (which can't to tun as service) I get exceptions on starting X.

So I want to know how I can run .sh files which are not services.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to run a command once at startup is to put it in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, which is a link from `/etc/rcX.d/S99local`, and gets run at the very end of the boot sequence.

It's better to write, debug and link a proper service startup script, but if you're pushed for time and just want to whack in a one-line launch command, I find that's the best place to run it from.